# asp.net : need to see the difference between 2 web.config file

Tags: asp.net

What is the fastest and safest way to download a tool and see the difference between the 2 web.config files? Does windows xp has a built in tool to do a visual Diff on 2 files?

I am running Windows XP professional SP3 on my computer.

Would downloading Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools cause an issue?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).  However unless this is some simple throwaway code, or web.config from two different projects, you should have this all in a version control system.  It could be SVN like Aliostad mentioned.  In that case you can see the history of changes and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Try [WinDiff](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159214), it should come with XP.

Answer (score 1):

try windiff which comes with Windows SDK.

You can also install SVN tortoise and create a dummy repository and add web.config to see the difference. Diff viewer on tortoise is excellent.

Comment: Agreed.  DiffViewer in tortoise is the best I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing built in, but there are plenty of free diff tools around.

If you want something from Microsoft, you could try windiff, which is included in the [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

[TotalCommander](http://www.ghisler.com/)